# Close a page and redirect to previous page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to find a way to close a document page that is opened when a user clicks a link, but the document is not found and then displays a message as such. I've currently got the message and check for it working, but I'm running into issues with closing said document page and redirecting/refreshing the page the user tried to open the document from. I've tried `Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri)` which gets me to the correct page, but the problem now is the document page is left open creating duplicate pages. Is there an easier way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like this - ( in general sense) - you opened gmail.com and then you want to open facebook.com in same tab, for the sake of that you want to close gmail.com tab and open a new tab, open facebook.com in that newly opened tab?, But if you open facebook.com , directly in gmail opened tab, by just manually erasing gmail.com and type facebook.com, the purpose and result will still be same.

Comment: @ArindamNayak - My apologies for the unclear explanation, I am a highly visual creature. I suppose what I mean is (in general sense following your example), if I am in gmail.com and I click a link, it opens facebook.com in a new tab. This is the good case. The bad case is that I am in gmail.com and I click a link to open facebook.com in a new tab, but the load fails and it closes the tab. What I am trying to do is send a response back that says the load failed and display that on the "gmail.com" page. Does that help? - Also, these pages are part of the same project.

Comment: So if all of pages ( opened in new tab) belong to same project , i mean they should load fine, then what is the point of checking the same? But yes, i have workaround for this - like while opening in new tab, do a ajax get query, if that succeed, then only open in new tab.